# wp7 CapabilityDetection.exe

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to determine what (and where) in my code is causing certain capabilities to be required?

When I run CapabilityDetection.exe against my bin folder it comes up with:
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER

Answer (score 1):

ID_CAP_MEDIALIB indicates that you're accessing the media library somewhere, but I've seen this reported incorrectly a lot. ID_CAP_NETWORKING means you're accessing a data connection at some point, ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER means that you're making a phone call, ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT means that you've go the `WebBrowser` control on at least one page. I don't think I've ever seen these reported in error. ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER means that you're using the anonymous Windows Live ID for user identification, which is typically the case when you're using a third party analytics solution such as mtiks or Flurry.

There's a list of the various capabilities on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28VS.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Capabilities). Generally speaking, if you don't think you're using a particular capability, take it out, and then check that your application still runs as expected.

Comment: So if I remove the capability from the manifest and run the project will it break where the capability is being used?

Comment: My concern isn't so much that its reporting these capabilities, Its that I would like to know where in code they are being used.  I have a feeling that ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER, ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT, and ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER  are caused by the AdControl, but how can I prove it?

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, the app will "break" (throw an exception) if a required capability is missing. You could provie it by commenting out the AdControl and re-running the Capability Detect tool.

Comment: I can take out everything but ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT and ID_CAP_NETWORKING and my app still works.  Since Microsoft rewrites the AppManifest when you submit your app, does that mean they will put back all 5 capabilities even though the app only seems to need 2 of them?   This concerns me because as a user I wouldn't download my app if I saw ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER, ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER.

Comment: I don't think they'll add back any caps that aren't included.

Comment: Everything I've read about app submition says that MS will retest the Capabilities and repackage the manifest file.

Comment: Yes, they will, but I don't think they'll add back caps that you don't need.